# java reflection :Avoid warning unchecked call to getConstructor(Class<?>...) as a member of the raw type Class

Tags: java, reflection

I have read this post

[java: unchecked call to getConstructor(java.lang.Class<?>...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238818/java-unchecked-call-to-getconstructorjava-lang-class)

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Class> entry : connectionRepository.entrySet()) {
            if (/*someconditionhere*/) {
                try {
                    cwsConnection = (CWSConnection)entry.getValue().getConstructor().newInstance();
                    break;
                } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                    logger.error("Could not Create instance of CWSConnection for site version:\"{}\" Error:\"{}\"", entry.getKey(), e.getMessage(), e);
                } 
            }
        }
```

While compiling this piece of code I am getting a warning

> warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to getConstructor(Class...) as a member of the raw type Class

I just wanted to get the default constructor of CWSConnection, therefore, I should not pass any parameters to getConstructor(Class...) method.
Is there any better approach to get the default constructor(The one without arguments)

(I know `@SupressWarning` annotation will suppress this warning.)

Comment: Can you try also CWSConnection.class.cast(entry.getValue().getConstructor().newInstance());

Comment: Tried but still getting warning

Comment: Ok what about: Class<?> klass = entry.getValue();
            Constructor<?> constructor = klass.getConstructor();
            cwsConnection = constructor.newInstance();

Comment: That works perfectly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change your loop declaration to

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Class<?>> entry : connectionRepository.entrySet()) {
```

You've got this error because you use parametrised `Class` as a raw type. [Here you can read about generics and wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). You can use `Class<?>` and avoid this error. But cast to `CWSConnection` is still required. You can avoid it by owning a `Map<String, Class<CWSConnection>>` instead of `Map<String, Class<?>>`.

Answer (score 1):

The method

```
Class.newInstance()
```

calls the default constructor of the class. But I don't think this help you with the warnings, because your `Class` is still a raw type.

Comment: This does not really answer the question; it might be better suited as a comment, as the core of the question were indeed the warnings.

Comment: @UweAllner The part "is there any better approach to get the default constructor" is enough of a question for me. YMMV